# GEE: exporting and handling Google Open Buildings

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have run issues with Google Open Buildings and using zonal statistics in Google Earth Engine. Here is a [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/025b515e3b2973f0b3c48f832f8a6d4e) to my code. Please note that this code contains assets.

I subset the buildings to one country in my code and then ran zonal statistics using an image asset. I then filtered the buildings again based on the zonal statistics result.

Exporting the buildings from GEE takes a significant amount of time. I left it running for many hours and it attempted the export 5 times. Screenshot of this:

[image: google open buildings failure to export]

I tried exporting the zonal statistics result as a CSV rather than a shapefile to reduce the size of the export. I am still long export times and multiple attempts.

I suspect the issue is the size of the Google Open Buildings data and the complexity of the many geometries. Do you have any advice for working with Google Open Buildings in GEE and getting around this?

Answer (score 1):

Freetown alone has 300,000 buildings.  Using even that small subset as a single geometry (with > 1 million points), in a reduceRegion isn't ever going to work well.  You *might* get it to work, eventually, using reduceRegions, where the polygons aren't lumped into one giant geometry.

Also, no reason to filter for sum > 0, if you're just summing them.  The zeros wont matter.

Comment: What do you recommend using to get zonal statistics for the Google Open Buildings?